# Removing an Index From MongoDB in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to delete an index from the database that I put before.

```java
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String name;
```

After I delete the `@Indexed(unique = true)`, I need to remove it from the `MongoDB` too. And I need to do it within Spring. Can I do it with `@PostConstruct` or something?

Answer (score 6):

Spring-Data's `MongoTemplate` has a method to give you `IndexOperations` for a collection which lets you create and drop indices of a collection.

**Attention:** 
According to [db.collection.dropIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) documentation the drop of a index will lock the whole collection until its dropped and all queries using the index are killed.

Here is an example which deletes an index 'name' from the collection 'products' during app start.

```
@Component
class IndexManager implements InitializingBean {

    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public IndexManager(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        mongoTemplate.indexOps("products").dropIndex("name");
    }
}
```

There are multiple ways to execute code during spring application startup. More ways to do it can be found here: [running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring)

Comment: dropIndex method needs real name of index that have generated base on field name. so you can not use dropIndex with field name

Answer (score 6):

I solve this with using @PostConstruct. While app is initializing I did remove the index with MongoTemplates. The Code is like this:

```
    @PostConstruct
    private void removeIndex() {
        IndexOperations indexOperations = mongoTemplate.indexOps(YourEntity.class);
        Optional<IndexInfo> indexInfo = indexOperations.getIndexInfo().stream().filter(i->i.getName().contains("name_")).findFirst();
        if(indexInfo.isPresent()) {
            indexOperations.dropIndex("name");
        }
    }
```